# Retrieve the copied link from clipboard via Cypress Headless returns: Your callback function returned a promise that never resolved

Tags: hyperlink, copy, cypress, clipboard

Please I need some help.
I'm trying to retrieve a link that is copied on the clipboard after I click on a button via Cypress and the code works with no issues if I use the OPEN mode. Using the RUN mode (headless), the function doesn't work and returns "Your callback function returned a promise that never resolved."
I imagine because it's headless and has some problems to catch the window() function.
How can I fix this, I need to run it headless and still catch this link

This is my function - I'm adding only the relevant part for the copy link

```
function checkLinkStatus(collectionName) {
  cy.get(this.dataLabelForCollection).each((collection, index) => {
  if (collection.text() === collectionName) {
     cy.get(this.copyCollectionLinkBtn).eq(index).realClick();
     cy.window().then((win) => {
       return win.navigator.clipboard.readText().then((copyLink) => {
          cy.wrap(copyLink).as('collectionLink');
         });
      });
    }
  });
}
```